# Google search vs FAST ESP - what are the tech differences?

Tags: search, search-engine, fast-esp

I'm doing a presentation for Sr. Tech Managers and trying to figure out a quick overview of the tech differences of Google and FAST.

Yes, I've googled, but nothing concrete (except marketing materials).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117388/google-search-fast-esp-and-lucene

Answer (score 0):

[image]

SharePoint 2013 has absorbed FAST and integrated it to its enterprise search available out of the box. Obviously, if you purchased FAST for SharePoint 2010 you may be a little sour about this. The benefits however are enormous, the new algorithm, topology architecture, scalability, query suggestions and many other things it brings to the table make it undeniably the best update in SharePoint 2013.

New Features list for 2013 here: http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-features-webinar-recording

[If you didn't arrive here for anything related to SharePoint - go with Google Search]